# How to remove invalid file name from uploaded file using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to validate the file name that has been uploaded like `"google6ca527072a20e5ad (6).html"` and `"sitemap (5).xml"`.

How to remove `(6)` and `(5)` these text from `uploaded file`?

I want to allow the user to upload valid webmaster files with valid extension.

Thank in advance.

Comment: (5) and (6) are special chaaracters? I think you first explain your definition of special characters!

Comment: Those two files contain "(", ")". How can I get only the filename.

Comment: Do you want to remove only the special characters"(",")" or you want to eliminate (5) or (6) from the filename?

Comment: Yes .I want to eliminate (5) or (6) from uploaded file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this once:

```
1.9.3-p545 :014 > line = "google6ca527072a20e5ad (6).html"
 => "google6ca527072a20e5ad (6).html" 
1.9.3-p545 :015 > line = line.gsub(/(\(.*\))/, '')
 => "google6ca527072a20e5ad .html" 
1.9.3-p545 :016 >
```

Comment: Thanks, It's useful. I converted into Jquery.
 line = line.replace(/\s+/, "") //Removed white space
 line = line.replace(/(\(.*\))/, '') //eliminated (6)

Answer (score 0):

if it is always at the end of the filename you can try this:

```
var extension = line.substr( (line.lastIndexOf('.') +1) );
//get the extension - in this case it is html

var filename = line.substr(0, line.lastIndexOf('.'));
//get the filename - in this case it is google6ca527072a20e5ad (6)

filename.slice(0,-4);
var finalFile=filename+'.'+extension;

//would result => google6ca527072a20e5ad.html
```